# what device do i pick for boot loader installation? (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2

I'm installing Ubuntu 20.04 on my laptop, i already have Win10 and Ubuntu 18.04 installed. I've made a 40 GB SSD "/" partition and 100 GB HDD "/home" partition. The last thing left to do is pick a device for boot loader installation and my options are -

```
/dev/sda ATA ST1000LM035-1RK1 (1.0 TB)
/dev/sda2
/dev/sda3
/dev/sda4 Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS (18.04)
/dev/sdb ATA TOSHIBA KSG60ZMV (256.1 GB)
/dev/sdb1 Windows Boot Manager
/dev/sdb3
/dev/sdb4
/dev/sdb5
/dev/sdb6
```

I'm guessing that I'm going to have to shrink a volume from the ssd and assign it as the device for boot loader installation just like the windows Boot Manager, but i'm not sure how much memory to shrink. What do I do??

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. It is normally recommended that bootloader goes on sda, not on a partition. It will merge with your Ubuntu 18.04 bootloader.

Comment: thanks! I did some research on bootloaders and did the same as you said

Comment: I don't know whether this will help you, since you asked this a lot earlier from when I'm seeing it. I've been trying to look for the same and at last thought of going with this guide of "Installation of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS-Dual Boot". This might solve your query for selecting the Boot Loader. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-iSAyiicyQY

Comment: Be aware of launchpad bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379  Installer uses first EFI system partition found even when directed otherwise.  Do add yourself to the "Does this affect me" list and maybe someday it will get fixed.